# select option metabox with value count

Tags: php, wordpress, count, meta-boxes

i'm new early for wordpress and php code.

so, i have post type property with type ( apartment, house, villa, etc ). example, for type apartment any three property. but on select option, be like this :

--Type

-Apartment

-Apartment

-Apartment.

so, i want like this :

--Type

-Apartment(3)

but, i use with count. not work for me.

so, this my code :

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'property',
'posts_per_page'    => -1
);
$property = get_posts($args);
```

and this my code select option.

```
<select name="type">
<option>Type</option>
<?php  foreach( $property as $homes ) {
$type = get_post_meta($homes->ID, 'type', true);
if ( $type == '---') continue;
$new_type = count($type);
echo '<option value="'.$homes->ID.'">'.$new_type.'</option>';
 } ?>
</select>
```

anyone can help me? thanks in advance. regards

Comment: Use PHP function `count`. I have not gone through all code in detail.But You can do like this : `$new_type = count($type);` and then put it next to the $type. And make select box out of the foreach loop.

Comment: thanks for reply, `<option>'.$new_type.'</option>.'`  but this value be Type : 1 1 1, because counted one by one. :(

Comment: Can you Edit your post with updated code ?

Comment: I guess you have not read my whole comment.Use `foreach` loop outside the select box and then use it $new_type with the $type like this :
`echo '<option value="'.$homes->ID.'">'.$type($new_type).'</option>';`

Comment: sorry, I've been using like that the previous.. but select option can't display/missing on page.  :(

Comment: Can you give me the link of your site ? Or is it on local host ?

Comment: i still work on localhost..
I've spent time on today's for this case. :(

Comment: Okay .. I ll help you till I am free. Lets do it by debugging.
First of all remove select box code and add following :
`<?php  foreach( $property as $homes ) {
$type = get_post_meta($homes->ID, 'type', true);
} ?>
$new_type = count($type); echo $new_type; echo $type[0];`
And tell me its output here.

Comment: Put `echo $type;` inside the foreach and then tell me its output.

Comment: this output $type,  ApartmentApartmentApartmentVilla---House1.

number 1 is output from echo $new_type. and that outside the foreach

Comment: Ok .. Is it okay if we do with PHP ?Like We will make an array of this result of above comment and then we will search for the string called Apartment and then we will make another array of the apartment and the we will count and we will get desire result. :)

Comment: its oke, if you don't mind and a litle bit washing your time with this case, :)

Comment: Ok .. I will put here after some time.Till than you also try different logic.

Comment: oke. although I'm fairly new to php code. but i'll try to..